# Save as List Template of document library which has 18000 documents!

Tags: 2013, document-library, list-template

I have one document library which has around 18000 documents(Total size of the all document is around 280 MB).

Now I want to make list template so I go to `Library Settings` and then click on `Save document library as template` and check `Include Content`.

Now after clicking on `OK` button, Request goes infinite, the **page is never responding**.

I have also tried this using PowerShell but it not helped. It throws following exception.

```
PS C:\Users\SP_Farm> $list.SaveAsTemplate("WFHistoryWithDocs","WFWithDocs","",$t
rue)
Exception calling "SaveAsTemplate" with "4" argument(s): "The list is too
large to save as a template. The size of a template cannot exceed 52428800
bytes."
At line:1 char:1
+ $list.SaveAsTemplate("WFHistoryWithDocs","WFWithDocs","",$true)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SPException*
```

So is there any other way to achieve my requirement?

Comment: You can give it a try using PowerShell script. You can refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.saveastemplate.aspx) link to get idea.

Comment: @Users1100 : I have also tried with PowerShell but not luck. You can check my updated question

Comment: After looking at the error you are receiving, I think you should increase the size of maximum limit of Save List As Template. You can follow the instructions mentioned at [this](http://sharepointyankee.com/2008/12/18/increase-the-%E2%80%98save-as-template%E2%80%99-size-limit-for-lists-and-sites/) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved using PowerShell.

As "User1100" suggested I did need to set maximum list template size using following command

```
stsadm -o setproperty -propertyname max-template-document-size -propertyvalue 367001600
```

Or in SharePoint Powershell

```
$docSize = 367001600
$webservice = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$webservice.MaxTemplateDocumentSize = $docSize
$webservice.Update()
```

Then also list template was not being saved then I realized that default maximum size for document in document library is 50MB by default (as List Template Gallery is document library). So I updated maximum document size from Central Admin - Manager Web Application - General Setting.

after that `$list.SaveAsTemplate("WFHistoryWithDocs","WFWithDocs","",$t
rue)` worked successfully

Thanks

Comment: Also max size for this setting is `524288000`

Answer (score 0):

And for those without powershell skills :
Delete All items, save as template and then restore the deleted items.
Ugly hack but it works

Comment: Wouldnt do that on production :-)